# MariaDB InnoDB table: how to find statement causing "waiting for table metadata lock"

Tags: mariadb

How do I determine what the SQL statement is of the thread ID showing up in a metadata lock info row (SELECT * FROM information_schema.metadata_lock_info) on MariaDB?

```
Server version: 10.0.15-MariaDB MariaDB Server
```

All of the related questions dive into the "Waiting for table metadata lock" from a MySQL perspective, but that does not help with MariaDB since their introspection is implemented differently from what I can tell. Googling around does not turn up a whole lot.

A "show full processlist" gives rows like:

```
| 57295 | main  | localhost | joints | Execute |   50 | Waiting for table metadata lock | select ...
```

Which does show the statement, but does not show that it has the lock either. So, I turned on metadata lock info as explained here [0]. This only provides the thread ID of the lock holder, but not the statement:

```
MariaDB [joints]> SELECT * FROM information_schema.metadata_lock_info;
+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+
| THREAD_ID | LOCK_MODE                | LOCK_DURATION   | LOCK_TYPE            | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME     |
+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+
|     57322 | MDL_INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE  | MDL_EXPLICIT    | Global read lock     |              |                |
|     57322 | MDL_SHARED_NO_READ_WRITE | MDL_EXPLICIT    | Table metadata lock  | joints       | 16_study       |
|     57322 | MDL_INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE  | MDL_EXPLICIT    | Schema metadata lock | joints       |                |
|     57269 | MDL_SHARED_READ          | MDL_TRANSACTION | Table metadata lock  | joints       | authentication |
|     57301 | MDL_SHARED_READ          | MDL_TRANSACTION | Table metadata lock  | joints       | authentication |
|     57280 | MDL_SHARED_READ          | MDL_TRANSACTION | Table metadata lock  | joints       | authentication |
|     57317 | MDL_SHARED_READ          | MDL_TRANSACTION | Table metadata lock  | joints       | ship           |
|     57271 | MDL_SHARED_READ          | MDL_TRANSACTION | Table metadata lock  | joints       | administration |
|     57264 | MDL_SHARED_READ          | MDL_TRANSACTION | Table metadata lock  | joints       | server         |
+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+
```

What I really want is to see the "join" of both of those outputs at the moment the locking is happening. I do not see a way to join the data from these two "tables" since the former does not appear to be a table. I'd like to avoid getting:

```
ERROR 1933 (HY000): Target is not running an EXPLAINable command
```

while attempting to do it in real-time, due to the thread ending while being inspected.

[0] https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/metadata_lock_info/

Comment: Is Replication involved?  Did `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` not give any clues?  Do users use `autocommit=0`?

Comment: No replication (single server). Generally autocommit=1. The show full processlist was full of transactions that were locked out, but did not help identify which one had the lock.

Comment: Either look for the item that is not in "Lock" state, or it is a transaction that has not COMMITted yet and is between SQLs.  Look for the largest "Time" (skipping any that are obviously system threads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREAD_ID` maps to `information_schema.PROCESSLIST.ID` (the first column in `show 
[full] processlist;`. ie:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.METADATA_LOCK_INFO AS mli
JOIN information_schema.PROCESSLIST AS pl ON mli.THREAD_ID = pl.ID
```

I am preferential towards something like the following to make it easier to see the what is happening (the newlines don't work well with the cli though):

```
SELECT
  mli.THREAD_ID, mli.LOCK_MODE, mli.LOCK_TYPE, 
  CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(mli.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', mli.TABLE_NAME) ORDER BY mli.TABLE_SCHEMA, mli.TABLE_NAME SEPARATOR '\n') AS CHAR) AS locked_tables, 
  pl.USER, pl.HOST, pl.DB, pl.COMMAND, pl.TIME, pl.STATE, pl.INFO, pl.QUERY_ID, pl.TID
FROM information_schema.METADATA_LOCK_INFO AS mli
JOIN information_schema.PROCESSLIST AS pl ON mli.THREAD_ID = pl.ID
GROUP BY mli.THREAD_ID, mli.LOCK_MODE, mli.LOCK_TYPE
ORDER BY time DESC, pl.ID;
```

Especially interesting is when `pl.COMMAND = 'Sleep'` as that indicates some connection pool or other (mostly read-only) program is holding open connections that have locks on them.